# How to fix Column Index out of range SQLException

Tags: java, mysql, exception

When i'm passing a query i'm getting below error.

```
 Errorno is Nil
 Error String Is Query Problem.....
 java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 2 > 1.
```

This is the code in my `java` method.

```
PreparedStatement pstm=con.prepareStatement("select period from stu_attendancemaster where classid=? and absentdt>=? and absentdt<=?");
pstm.setInt(1,classid);
pstm.setDate(2,fromdt);
pstm.setDate(3,todt);
System.out.println("qry for prd "+pstm.toString());
rs=pstm.executeQuery();
System.out.println("after qry for prd "+pstm.toString());

if(rs.next())   {
    stame = new Stu_AttendanceMasterEntity(rs.getInt(1), rs.getDate(2), rs.getInt(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getInt(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getTimestamp(7), rs.getString(8), rs.getTimestamp(9),rs.getString(10),rs.getInt(11),rs.getString(12));
}   else    {
    flag=false;
    errorstring=FN + P1 +" Class Name: " + Dep_ClassMasterDB.getClassname(classid) +" From Date: " +DateUtility.displayDate(fromdt,0) +" To Date: " +DateUtility.displayDate(todt,0) +N + V +DNE;
}
}   catch(Exception e)  {
    flag=false;
    errorstring="Query Problem..... "+e;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Error is in this statement:

```
PreparedStatement pstm=con.prepareStatement("select period from stu_attendancemaster where classid=? and absentdt>=? and absentdt<=?");
```

you have to select all the 12 fields in your select query.

Ex: (I am assuming that you have 12 fields in your table `stu_attendancemaster`) Do this:

```
    PreparedStatement pstm=con.prepareStatement("select * from stu_attendancemaster where classid=? and absentdt>=? and absentdt<=?");
```

if not you can modify your query statement like this

```
select `colName1`, `colName2`, `colName3`, `colName4`, `colName5`, `colName6`, `colName7`, `colName8`, `colName9`, `colName10`, `colName11`, `colName12`,  from stu_attendancemaster where classid=? and absentdt>=? and absentdt<=?
```

**Note** : `colName*` should be your actual column name in the table.

**EDIT** : In case if you need only period from the query: just have `rs.getInt(1)` and remove `rs.getInt(2)` to `rs.getInt(12)`

**Rule of thumb is** : the number of column in the `select` clause and `ResultSet.getXXX()` should be same.

Comment: yeah but i want periods alone from this method

Comment: in that case use : `rs.getInt(1)`. Remove `rs.getInt(2)` to `rs.getInt(12)`

Answer (score 6):

You select one column in your statement and then access more than one column in your ResultSet.
To fix your problem, you have to select from your database what you later want to read from the ResultSet.

Comment: can you give little more explanation

Comment: Your query "select period from stu_attendancemaster where classid=? and absentdt>=? and absentdt<=?" is just selecting the column period from your table.
The ResultSet you are evaluating is accessing 12 different columns.
stame = new Stu_AttendanceMasterEntity(rs.getInt(1), rs.getDate(2), rs.getInt(3), ....
But only one, the period, is available.
If you access a column you did not select, you will receive the error you posted earlier.

Answer (score 1):

select statement is:

```
("select period from stu_attendancemaster where classid=? and absentdt>=? and absentdt<=?");
```

however you are getting more fields than period in your resultSet

```
rs.getInt(1), rs.getDate(2), rs.getInt(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getInt(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getTimestamp(7), rs.getString(8), rs.getTimestamp(9),rs.getString(10),rs.getInt(11),rs.getString(12));
```

you cannot get these data from the resultset when you are just selecting **period**.